# Powershell RegEx - String matches pattern, but is part of the string

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm new posting to this site, but use it extensively.

I'm using the following regex pattern:

```
(\w{2})_(\w{3}) (\w{2,4}) ([\w ]+) - ([\w ]+)
```

Works perfectly on any of the following Strings when trying to match:

```
Rg_Svr GB This is a Test - Permission
Rg_Svc TW ThisIsATest - Permission Also
```

It also works on the following, but I don't want it to:

```
Rg_Svc TW ThisIsATest - Permission Also - AndMoreText
Rg_Svc TW ThisIsATest - Permission Also - And More Text
```

Basically, I don't want Powershell to have a successful match if there is anything after the 5th Capturing Group.

Results from match are:

```
1.  [0-2]   `Rg`
2.  [3-6]   `Svc`
3.  [7-9]   `TW`
4.  [10-21] `ThisIsATest`
5.  [24-40] `Permission Also `
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your expression will match the first section of the text you do not want to match. You can add the `^` and `$` anchors to expect an *exact* match, something like so: `^(\w{2})_(\w{3}) (\w{2,4}) ([\w ]+) - ([\w ]+)$`. An example can be viewed [here](https://regex101.com/r/rX7wX3/1).